# Putting values in the next free cell in a specific sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make a VBA program that can put serial numbers in a list in a specific worksheet based on what the user enters via the rollbox.

This is what I have now:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Range("M:M")

    emptyRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange) + 1

    If ComboBox1.Value = "BMW" Then Sheets("BMW").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = serial_textbox.Text
    If ComboBox1.Value = "AUDI" Then Sheets("AUDI").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = serial_textbox.Text
    If ComboBox1.Value = "VW" Then Sheets("VW").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = serial_textbox.Text
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Porsche" Then Sheets("Porsche").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = serial_textbox.Text
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Lamborghini" Then Sheets("Lamborghini").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = serial_textbox.Text
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it only enters the values in A1 (in the correct sheet) and pasts it over each other.

Comment: `MyRange` is not defined as any of the sheets referred to below (in fact no sheet is specified) so that is probably the problem. Do you mean you want the results to start in M10?

Comment: I use a userform to input the serial number in a textbox and then I select the correct car via a rollbox (both in the same userform). So now I would like the serial numbers to start in the correct worksheet at M10, for all cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim wsSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set wsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value)
Set MyRange = wsSheet.Range("M:M")

emptyRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange) + 1
wsSheet.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = serial_textbox.Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can shorten your code as you are doing the same thing in each case and your sheet names correspond with the combobox list.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim emptyRow As Long

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(10, Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)

Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Cells(emptyRow, "M").Value = serial_textbox.Text

End Sub
```